# How to enumerate all possible errors in Java?

Tags: java, error-handling

I don't mean every error in an individual program, I mean every error possible in Java 8. Is there somewhere in the Java Docs where you can find it?

Comment: all subclasses of `Throwable` is your enumeration.

Comment: Does each subclass correspond to one error?

Comment: possibly I did not understand your question. what do you mean by enumerate all errors?

Comment: I meant obtaining a list of every type of error that can halt a program, and what initiates them.

Comment: Any exception, even a custom one, can halt the program if not caught.

Comment: Custom exceptions not withstanding, these are the things with which my list will be populated.

Comment: Too see the exceptions defined in the Java Runtime Library, start at [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), like @Mr.V. said, and begin drilling in on the "Direct Known Subclasses" (recursively). Alternatively, use an IDE, and find all classes ending in `*Exception` or `*Error`. Warning: It a very long list.

Comment: Alright, thank you, @Mr.V and Andreas this is exactly the thing for which I was looking.

Comment: No, because (a) Any programmer can declare his own exceptions, and if thrown and not caught, the program will halt. You can't enumerate what doesn't exist yet. (b) There is always a possibility of a bug in the JVM that will cause an asynchronous error. That's something that you don't know in advance what will initiate it. (c) People can use existing exceptions in their own way. So again the circumstances can't be known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me more of a research question rather than that of a solid implementation, but on any basis you have 2 lines of enquiry:

1) Any errors that can happen post compilation will only occur as instances of the Throwable type, if you want to track all of those down you'd need to include every single section of the runtime library (and any other possible user defined libraries included in your project) in a class that you intend to use to report them back to you or your running project program.  You would then iterate over all of the currently defined classes using Reflection populating as you go a list with anything that returns true as instanceof Throwable - thats assuming you want all of the possible class names.  The potential causes of those exceptions would only be hinted at by the documentation related to any given Throwable class.

2) On the other hand if you want all of the compile time-errors as well then you'll need to look in the source code for the Java compiler.

But in all honesty, the reason an exception is called an Exception is because it reports a fault based on an exceptional circumstance which you should be able to preempt during development.  Anything faulty enough to stop a program working throws an exception and to catch anything Throwable without discerning the specific type is not something that should be considered for implementation - except perhaps if using a last chance saloon mentality (if my software hasnt resolved this over every condition I can forsee then it may be able to reset to base zero without falling over completely).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a nice overview of these by looking at the [package tree view](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html) of the `java.lang` package and navigate to Throwable (you can get to this view by selecting *Tree* in the navigation bar)

[Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) is the root of all errors and exceptions in Java. Notable Exceptions are

- `java.lang.Error`: root of abnormal / fatal errors
- `java.lang.Exception`: root of checked exceptions [*]
- `java.lang.RuntimeException`: root of unchecked exceptions

[*] if extends Exception but not RuntimeException